# ASP.NET MVC managing ViewModels

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In our ASP.NET MVC 3 application, we displays a lot of information from various data sources as listed below

1. Action method parameters
2. Query string (which can not be used in model binding)
3. Session
4. WCF Service
5. Database

We have to combine the data from all above stated data sources, format and dispay it in a view.
How to divide the classes so that it will have better maintenability?
If we use view models, how to construct the view model by combining all information?
Where to Keep the mapping between Domain Model and View Model and vice Versa?

Answer (score 0):

> How to divide the classes so that it will have better maintenability?

By defining view models that will be specifically tailored for the requirements of your views.

> If we use view models, how to construct view model by combining all information?

You could define a view model that will contain all the necessary information you need to display in a given view. If there are shared widgets between your views you could have child view models that the main view model could reference as properties (composition). The child view models could then be reused in other contexts.

Comment: Yes, to construct those information we may need to access various data sources like Session, Input data, query string, Business Layer interaction, Where to keep all those codes? Is it in controller directly or to use some other classes, if other classes, what should be the name of the class-Helper?

Comment: The controller is the correct place to aggregate this information from the various data sources into the view model.

Comment: "Mapping" from all those sources to the view model could be also done in a mapping layer (MappingService), if it is more complex. So your Controller is not bloating up that much.

Comment: Thanks to Darin and Rookian. Also I would like to know what is the suggested method for mapping from ViewModel to Domain Model and Vice Versa. Is that recommended to keep Mapper class file for each ViewModel,DomainModel combination? Many people used to refer helper files. What should be the role of Helper file in UI Context? Should It be some sort Input/Output processing?

Comment: Personally I use [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/) for this task. As far as the Helper file in the UI context is concerned, this could be some logic to generate small portions of reusable markup in the view. It has nothing to do with the mapping logic between your domain models and your view models.

Comment: AutoMapper is one which is helpful when the ViewModel and Domian Model matches at least in majority of the properties/attributes. Usually there will be a definite mismatch between ViewModel and Domain model if you follow DDD. One major concerns regarding the construction of Views is to reduce the logical constructs like 'if' or data processing expression inside the view. Ideally this should be possible if you have a properly structured ViewModel which is in sync with the View; So if you want to flatten the domain classes or combine the data from Input, where should code be kept?